# Why would "quality of the gearbox" affect torque of a machine tool?

Tags: gears, torque

I read a manufacturer's web site which has the following statement:

> Some manufacturers promote their higher horsepower as a selling
>   feature over competitors. However, it is critical to recognize that
>   horsepower is not the determining criteria on saw performance, but
>   instead it is how much torque is delivered to the band wheels. The
>   amount of torque delivered to the wheels is based on the quality and
>   ratio of the gearbox. Today, the higher technology saws can both run
>   more efficiently and deliver more torque to the band wheels, with
>   lower horsepower than on older saws.

I understand the importance of the gear ratio. Higher gear ratio, more torque. However, why would the "quality" of the gearbox make any ddifference to the torque. If the gearbox is 24:1, then it is same whether it is an expensive high-quality gearbox or a cheapo gearbox, I would think. Why is the manufacturer saying that the gearbox quality affects the saw performance?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely due to frictional losses, which can affect the torque output for a certain ratio. The gear material and design will also determine the maximum torque it can handle.

Comment: I see, so a cheapo gearbox simply will not be able to handle the load, and therefore the machine designer of cheapo machine will not use a gearbox with a higher ratio that could stress out the gearbox. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, usually the torque output breaks gear boxes more than just the power output. So it would usually be cheaper to avoid a high gear ratio for a set amount of power output. For example 1HP at 3000 RPM would be a lot simpler to make than 1HP at 1RPM

Comment: Cheap gearboxes use spur gears with limited tooth stress, lower quality materials (hardness/surface finish), lower quality bearings and tolerances that may vary.  Other factors would be the overall system rigidity and ability to handle high starting torques.  A well engineered gearbox would account for the extremes of the operating conditions and therefore could be designed with a lower FoS (Factor of Safety) which may imply a lighter or smaller design.